# Script for Random splitting a Mesh into n pieces with m%

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to split a mesh randomly into N pieces by assigning user defined percentage (out of 100%) of faces to each nth-piece. As shown below.
In parallel, I would also like to have Random Seed that track history of these randomly split meshes 
.
[image: This is what I am trying to do]

I can select only 1 face at a time through the script but not multiple faces at a time getting following error 
.
[image]

This is my so far a try to accomplish this task:
    # Divide Mesh into n Pieces with m% 
    # for example: if n=3, User ask to input percentages for Piece 1,2 and 3
    # The percent should be 100% and pieces contain random faces in the mesh
    # The combination of pieces selection should also be random seeded.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

myobj = bpy.ops.mesh
myobj.primitive_plane_add()
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
myobj.subdivide(number_cuts=3,smoothness=1)
myobj.select_all(action='TOGGLE')

me = bpy.context.object
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me.data)

for i in range(len(bm.faces)): #in my test case 16 faces in total
    i = i + 2
    bm.faces[i].select=True #select every second face-Just checking if different pattern of selection works.

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me.data, True)
```

Once it select random faces in a mesh split them and make N pieces.

Comment: Not answer (what is the question exactly ?!) , but there is https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_63_7/bpy.ops.mesh.html#bpy.ops.mesh.select_random

Comment: Random selection will not give me the exact number of percentage of selection. How can I divide a mesh into N pieces with percent factor assign to each piece. I am a beginner in Python scripting.